# Add a field to a Taxonomy Term programmatically

Tags: orchardcms

I create a Taxonomy call "**Stuff**" when the module feature enabled. At that same time i'm adding a bodypart to it using AlterTypeDefinition, without any issue.

I now have a ContentType called "**Stuff Term**" with a bodypart attached. All good!

At the same point in the feature enablement, on the "**Stuff Term**" I'd like to add a field of type text called "**StuffId**" so that when I come to create/add my taxonomy terms for "**Stuff**" i can also update the "**StuffId**" field on the term with an ID of my choosing. This is so I can get the correct term by the "**StuffId**" during a synchronisation.

I can't seem to find an example of how to add a field to a contenttype programmatically.
I can see it can/must be added to a part but which Part of the "**Stuff Term**" contenttype should it be added?

Any direction would be gratefully received.

P.S.
I have lots of Stuff which is hierarchical and a couple which have the same name. However, the same name would never appear at the same level in the hierarchy. The path of the term gives the context to the Stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Add it to a part that has the same name as the type (the part does not need to pre-exist).

Comment: like so?:                _contentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(
     "Stuff Term", builder =>
                   builder.WithField("StuffID", fld =>
                          fld.OfType("text")
                          WithSetting("DisplayName", StuffID")));

Comment: Didn't work :-( 
When I looked at the "Stuff Term" content type in the dashboard there was not a field on it called "StuffID".
Am I barking up the right tree regarding putting a field on the a term content type?

Comment: Then you didn't get the part's name right. It needs to be the exact technical name of the type.